# "Unable to load class with name [org.ajax4jsf.taglib.html.facelets.ActionParamHandler]" after adding Richfaces

Tags: web-applications, jsf, glassfish

I am running a webapp on a glassfish v3 server. I've just added richfaces to my application, but I get an error when i try running my project:

```
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.2 (FCS b10) for context '/WMC'
INFO: Unsanitized stacktrace from failed start...
java.lang.RuntimeException: WEB9033: Unable to load class with name [org.ajax4jsf.taglib.html.facelets.ActionParamHandler], reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/facelets/tag/jsf/ComponentHandler
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:944)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1420)
        at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:203)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.loadClass(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:313)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processComponent(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:568)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:361)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:314)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:263)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:337)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:223)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4591)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:535)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5193)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1933)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1605)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/facelets/tag/jsf/ComponentHandler
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:914)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:949)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1420)
        ... 55 more
```

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
        <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
        <param-value>enable</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet><servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping><session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            10
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config><welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>mail/WMCMail_LogicalName</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.mail.Session</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

And I've added the following libs to my project

[image]

I've tried to include jsf-facelets.jar but this results in some version conflicts. Do you know what to do?

Comment: I've used the two components here http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=8934 to make richface availible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glassfish ships with builtin JSF 2.0 libraries. RichFaces 3.3.0 is not compatible with JSF 2.0.

You have 2 options:

1. Downgrade JSF 2.0 to JSF 1.2. You need to supply your own (or RichFaces-provided) JSF 1.2 libraries in `/WEB-INF/lib` and instruct Glassfish to use the supplied JSF instead by setting `useBundledJsf` property in `/WEB-INF/sun-web.xml` to `true`:

   ```
   <sun-web-app>
       <class-loader delegate="false"/>
       <property name="useBundledJsf" value="true"/>
   </sun-web-app>
   ```
2. Upgrade RichFaces 3.x to at least 3.3.3. It has partial JSF 2.0 support. How to get it to work is described in [this document](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFaces333andJSF20).

For full JSF 2.0 support by RichFaces, you've wait for RichFaces 4.0 to be final. As far now, [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) and [OpenFaces](http://openfaces.org) are one of the few with full JSF 2.0 support.

Comment: I think I will try OpenFaces then. It seems to be the easiest:). Don't really understand if my project is maven based ?

Comment: OpenFaces has a nice website with awesome looking components, but IMO it has not so wide community support yet. For PrimeFaces the community support is better. I have handson experience with it and also at their [own forum](http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewforum.php?f=3) the PF lead developer, Cagatay, will respond very well on problems. You might want to take this into consideration. A good community support is invaluable whenever you're encountering problems. BTW: PrimeFaces has awesome components as well. Did you find their [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/prime-showcase)?

Comment: PrimeFaces is available by Maven as well: http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html

Comment: I found their showcase. They also have very nice components. I'll take PrimeFaces then. It doesn't matter to me as long as it works.

Comment: And it does. Now I can select multiple rows in a datatable. Cool:)